# T-SQL JOIN between JOIN and ON

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could anyone elaborate me on what would be differences between these two?

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.UserProducts AS UP
INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS P
    ON P.ProductID = UP.ProductID
INNER JOIN dbo.Industry AS I
    ON I.IndustryCode = P.IndustryCode



SELECT *
FROM dbo.UserProducts AS UP
INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS P
    INNER JOIN dbo.Industry AS I
        ON I.IndustryCode = P.IndustryCode
    ON P.ProductID = UP.ProductID
```

I've seen second option explained on MSDN, however I cannot find this anymore and I think it was using LEFT JOINS.

Comment: For both examples, should the first inner join not be `... AS P` rather than `... AS UP`?

Comment: wow second one looks really gross.  "How can i make this as hard as possible for future developers to understand.  Yay job security!" :P

Comment: @Kritner Annoyingly, SQL Server Management Studio's query designer generally generates queries using that second method of writing joins. It is an absolute nightmare to then read through them and figure out what columns the tables join on.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yucky.  Guess I've never actually even used the query designer :D

Comment: Yup, alias was written wrong, my bad.I just wanted to point out syntax differences. So there's no real difference between those two when executing, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [grammar for `FROM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) explains this.

The syntax is `FROM { <table_source> }`.

And `<table_source>` can be one of several things, including `<joined_table>`.

And `<joined_table>` can consist of:

```
<table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition>
```

So a `<table_source>` can be a join to a `<table_source>`, which can itself be a join, etc.

Your first example is "UserProducts, joined to Products; and Products joined to Industry".

The second is "UserProducts, joined to (Products and Industry joined together)"

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing different between the two examples from a logic perspective, one is just far easier to read.

Sometimes it can actually makes sense to put all the criteria below all the joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
LEFT JOIN table3 c
  ON     a.col1 = c.col1
  ON     b.ID = c.ID
```

But in general it's easier to read when the criteria immediately follows the `JOIN`

Comment: Not sure how this example supports your point; there's no reason to join these tables in this order, apart from the arbitrary names and aliases you used.

Comment: That statement doesn't have enough `ON` clauses.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Thanks for that, it's so counter-intuitive to put multiple `ON` clauses at the end that even when pointing out a situation where it might make sense my brain didn't want to do it.  Updated.